# Display data from database to RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Hello can you help me to display data from database to RecyclerView. I searched everywhere but in vain. I succeeded to do that with ListView and mysql but with RecyclerView I found difficulties.

UPDATE

UsersFragment.java

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_users, container, false);
        listView  = (ListView)   rootview.findViewById(R.id.listView);
        inputSearch  = (EditText)   rootview.findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);

        inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
                // When user changed the Text
                ((SimpleAdapter) UsersFragment.this.adapter).getFilter().filter(cs);

            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                                          int arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        });
        getJSON();
        return rootview;
    }

    private void showEmployee(String json){
        JSONObject jsonObject = null;
        ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        try {
            JSONArray result = new JSONArray(json);

            for(int i = 0; i<result.length(); i++){
                JSONObject jo = result.getJSONObject(i);
                String name = jo.getString("Nom");
                String email = jo.getString("Email");
                String login = jo.getString("Login");

                HashMap<String,String> employees = new HashMap<>();

                employees.put("name",name);
                employees.put("email",email);
                employees.put("login",login);
                list.add(employees);
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                getActivity(), list, R.layout.list_row,
                new String[]{"name","email"},
                new int[]{R.id.nom, R.id.email2});


        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
    private void getJSON() {
        class GetJSON extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
            ProgressDialog loading;
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                loading = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(), "Téléchargement", "Veuillez patientez...", false, false);
            }
            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
                super.onPostExecute(s);
                loading.dismiss();
                JSON_STRING = s;
                showEmployee(s);
            }
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
                RequestHandler rh = new RequestHandler();
                String s = rh.sendGetRequest(URL);
                return s;
            }
        }
        GetJSON gj = new GetJSON();
        gj.execute();
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), ViewMedecins.class);
        HashMap<String, String> map = (HashMap) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
        String tid = map.get("login").toString();
        intent.putExtra("login", tid);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

fragment_users.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <!-- Editext for Search -->
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:id="@+id/inputSearch" />
    <ListView android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btn1"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:layout_gravity="right|top" />
</FrameLayout>
```

list_row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/nom"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/email2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Update2

```
     public class UserListActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
            private String JSON_STRING;
public static final String URL="http://medicalrepresentative.comxa.com/Scripts/getAllProd.php";
            ArrayList<Contact> contacts;

            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                // ...
                // Lookup the recyclerview in activity layout
                RecyclerView rvContacts = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rvContacts);

                // Initialize contacts
                contacts = Contact.createContactsList(20);
                // Create adapter passing in the sample user data
                ContactsAdapter adapter = new ContactsAdapter(contacts);
                // Attach the adapter to the recyclerview to populate items
                rvContacts.setAdapter(adapter);
                // Set layout manager to position the items
                rvContacts.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
                // That's all!
            }

        }
```

Contact.java

```
public class Contact {
    private String mName;
    private String mRef;

    public Contact(String name, String ref) {
        mName = name;
        mRef = ref;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return mName;
    }
    public String getRef() {
        return mRef;
    }

    public static ArrayList<Contact> createContactsList(int numContacts) {
        ArrayList<Contact> contacts = new ArrayList<Contact>();

        try {
            JSONArray result = new JSONArray(json);
            for(int i = 0; i<result.length(); i++){
            JSONObject jo = result.getJSONObject(i);
                String name = jo.getString("Nom");
                String ref = jo.getString("Reference");

                HashMap<String,String> employees = new HashMap<>();

                employees.put("name",name);
                employees.put("ref",ref);
            contacts.add(new Contact(employees));
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return contacts;
    }
}
```

ContactsAdapter.java

```
public class ContactsAdapter extends
        RecyclerView.Adapter<ContactsAdapter.ViewHolder> {
```

public static final String URL = "http://aaaa.com/getall/getusers.php";

```
    // Provide a direct reference to each of the views within a data item
    // Used to cache the views within the item layout for fast access
    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        // Your holder should contain a member variable
        // for any view that will be set as you render a row
        public TextView nameTextView;
        public TextView refTextView;

        // We also create a constructor that accepts the entire item row
        // and does the view lookups to find each subview
        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            // Stores the itemView in a public final member variable that can be used
            // to access the context from any ViewHolder instance.
            super(itemView);

            nameTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.nom);
            refTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.email2);
        }
    }
    private List<Contact> mContacts;

    // Pass in the contact array into the constructor
    public ContactsAdapter(List<Contact> contacts) {
        mContacts = contacts;
    }
    @Override
    public ContactsAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        Context context = parent.getContext();
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

        // Inflate the custom layout
        View contactView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_contact, parent, false);

        // Return a new holder instance
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(contactView);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    // Involves populating data into the item through holder
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ContactsAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
        // Get the data model based on position
        Contact contact = mContacts.get(position);

        // Set item views based on the data model
        TextView textView = viewHolder.nameTextView;
        TextView textView2 = viewHolder.refTextView;
        textView.setText(contact.getName());
        textView2.setText(contact.getRef());

    }

    // Return the total count of items
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mContacts.size();
    }
}
```

Errors
Error:(33, 46) error: cannot find symbol variable json
Error:(43, 26) error: constructor Contact in class Contact cannot be applied to given types;
required: String,String
found: HashMap
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Comment: Can you post any piece of code, i cant see your code.

Comment: Please update your code with what you have tried so far with RecyclerView

Comment: I updated my post can you help me to correct it please

Answer (score 0):

Ok in `RecyclerView` you need to 3 steps :

1. Model Class - in the tutorial `Contact` class- (**Model**)
2. Row XML (like of your list_row.xml) - in the tutorial Creating the Custom Row Layout section (**View**)
3. And `Adapter`, `Viewholder` - in the tutorial Creating the `RecyclerView.Adapter` section (**Controller**)

You can see a very good tutorial in [Using-the-RecyclerView](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Using-the-RecyclerView)

I suggest you create an empty project to understand how `RecyclerView` works. If you understand it once it's enough for you to create tons of`RecyclerViews`. Have a good day.

Comment: thanks yes I have idea about this but the problem is how can I do the link between this code and my methods getJSON and showEmployee

Comment: If you create an empty project you can understand. Because you need to pass any ArrayList<Employee> to your adapter. In for loop you can add new Employees to your arraylist

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the data in onBindViewHolder() in your RecyclerView Adapter.

use RecyclerView tag instead of ListView tag in your XML.

Comment: I updated my post can you help me to correct it please